# How to apply border radius after drawing a rectangle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Photoshop doesn't support to apply border radius after drawing of rectangle. I found [this link](http://bjango.com/articles/roundrect/) and tried myself but seems to be not working. Is there any step is missed or is there any other idea to apply border radius after drawing a rectangle?

Comment: I'm doing blur method here...

Comment: This is a duplicate, but it should be said that in Photoshop Creative Cloud you know have the option to change the properties of a rectangle after you draw the rectangle

Answer (score 3):

Using script plugin we can add border radius in photoshop. 
Here you can find the plugins. 
http://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/rounded-rectangle-radius-resizer/

Installation

Copy and paste plugins here "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS4\Presets\Scripts".

Open Photoshop file , you can run the script from **File->Scripts-> Rounded_Rectangle_Radius_Resizer**.

Comment: I wouldn't be recommending a script when the OP doesn't know how to do it from the tools provided in the software...  just my 2

Answer (score 2):

In the new photoshop cc, you can now change the border radius via the shape properties panel.

[image]